# js element percentage of viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate the ratio (percentage) of a visible (on-screen) element in relation to the viewport height (not the percentage of the on-screen element!). Elements are always 100% width, therefore, at any given point there will always be a maximum of 2 elements on screen i.e. part of an element above, and one below. So far I was able to write the code, which calculates the top element correctly, but the element below (following the first element) is still wrong. What am I doing wrong?

[here is the code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m82y35c/1/)

```
    <section id="0" class="window" style="height: 150vh; background-color: #004444">
    <div class="smth"></div>
</section>
<section id="1" class="window" style="height: 150vh; background-color: #003333">
    <div class="smth"></div>
</section>
<section id="2" class="window" style="height: 150vh; background-color: #002222">
    <div class="smth"></div>
</section>

$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){

    var win = $(window);

    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft()
    };
    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

};

$.fn.ratioVisible = function(){
    var s = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(!this.isOnScreen()) return 0;
    var curPos = this.offset();
    var curTop = curPos.top - s;
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    var blockHeight = this.height();

    var ratio = ((curPos.top + blockHeight - s) / screenHeight);
    if(ratio > 1) ratio = 1 - (ratio - 1);

    return ratio;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that percentage for top element is correct? Also, can [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m82y35c/2/) help you?

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thanks!